# How to make turtles move along a list of locations in order

Tags: list, indexing, distance, netlogo, closest

My objective is to have an agentset (named ships) hatch at another agentset (named ports and listed in index) containing 2 locations representing the start and end of a pathway. To go- start moving ships/ heading towards a third agentset (called waypoints and listed in index1) in their given order.
However, if a port is closer to the current waypoint than another waypoint- move to port instead. Once the ships have reached the other port, I would also like them to stop.

Currently I have the model working with only two agentsets (ships and ports) however I would like to include a third set(called waypoints) to prevent ships from hatching at all locations(ports and waypoints) and to have the ships move in a sequential order by traveling along the waypoints (like stepping stones) before reaching the beginning or the end (ports).

Here is an example of my code:

```
breed [ships ship]
breed [ports port]
breed [waypoints waypoint]
ships-own [target-port
  current-port]

to setup
ca

 let index 0  
 create-ports 2
 [ let loc item index [ [0 -32] [32 0] ] 
   setxy (item 0 loc) (item 1 loc) 
   set index index + 1  
   set shape "circle" 
   set size 2
   set color red - 1]   

 let index1 0 
 create-waypoints 2
 [let loc item index1 [[12 -3] [14 -26]]
   setxy (item 0 loc) (item 1 loc)
   set index1 index1 + 1
   set shape "circle"
   set size 1
   set color red - 1]

 ask ports
[  let s who
   hatch-ships 1
 [ set current-port s
   set size 1
   set color red
   pen-down  
   set pen-size 1
   set target-port min-one-of ports with [ who != s] [distance myself] 
   set heading towards target-port  
  ] 
]
   reset-ticks 
end

to go 

;(obey-elevation)
ask ships 
[   if (distance target-port = 0) 
 [  let other_ports no-turtles
    ask target-port [set other_ports (other ports)]
    set target-port min-one-of other_ports [distance myself]
    face target-port
 ]
  ifelse (distance target-port < 1) 
  [ move-to target-port
  ]
    [fd 1
    ]
]

  tick
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using links to define the permitted paths? That is, create turtles (hidden and not moving) at the various locations of ports and waypoints and ties from waypoint to waypoint etc. The tie could have an attribute for 'travel-cost' which represents physical distance, difficulty travelling etc. You can then minimise the total travel cost or number of waypoints to identify the path that a ship takes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I am new to netlogo, I am not sure of the capabilities of links. Is it possible to have links connect from location to location without representing a constantly 'straight' path. I have the turtles moving along large distances and would not want to have "nodes"  or waypoints every time the turtle would need to move based on different rules restricting movement. Or would the best way to accomplish this by setting nodes at every possible patch in the world?

Comment: Straight line from one node to next but nodes can be in any positions (eg wherever there is a waypoint). Have a look in the Models Library (File menu) > Code Examples > Link-Walking Turtles Example.